# Can't connect to a local apache installation under XAMPP on Win XP 64-bit. Help!

Tags: windows, apache, 64-bit, xampp

I'm using XAMPP v1.7 on an Win XP-64 bit machine, my Symantec AV is turned off as is my Windows Firewall, and I can't connect to localhost from a browser.

I originally had these errors:
[Wed Jan 07 16:24:55 2009] [error] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : Child 2716: Encountered too many errors accepting client connections. Possible causes: dynamic address renewal, or incompatible VPN or firewall software. Try using the Win32DisableAcceptEx directive

These errors went away after I added the Win32DisableAcceptEx directive to httpd.conf, but the net result remains the same: no joy.

Now, I get these errors:
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:15 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11
 OpenSSL/0.9.8i mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:15 2009] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:15 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5916
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:15 2009] [notice] Disabled use of AcceptEx() WinSock2 API
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:15 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication
 ...
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:15 2009] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:15 2009] [notice] Child 5916: Child process is running
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:15 2009] [notice] Child 5916: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:15 2009] [notice] Child 5916: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:15 2009] [notice] Child 5916: Listening on port 443.
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:15 2009] [notice] Child 5916: Listening on port 80.
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:15 2009] [error] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that 
is not a socket.  : Too many errors in select loop. Child process exiting.
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:15 2009] [notice] Child 5916: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:16 2009] [notice] Child 5916: Released the start mutex
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:17 2009] [notice] Child 5916: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:17 2009] [notice] Child 5916: Child process is exiting
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:17 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 0 -- Restarting.
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:17 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jan 07 16:40:17 2009] [notice] Digest: done

And, apache seems to be crashing (Windows tells me so, and I can see the crash in the system events.)

I'm a n00b to apache, but need to get this running.  Ideas?
Marcus

Answer (score 9):

If anyone comes across this, try running

netsh winsock RESET

from the command line.  It worked for me.

Comment: Awesome - I got this problem after an AV install and this fixed it - I love this site :-)